# Can we use Microsoft Emotion API in our Android Apps

Tags: java, android, emotion

Can we use Microsoft Emotion API in our Android Apps, considering the fact that it's still in its 'Preview' mode, can we create our own customized app using the code of EMOTION API to recognize the moods of users in our own app?

Comment: you should ask microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

There is a public Github repo where you can find the Microsoft Emotion API sdk for Android!

https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Emotion-Android

Comment: Yeah that is the SDK for it which acts as a sample app for the emotion API but what i wanted to know is that if we can use the features of EMOTION api in our own custom made app.